# Error in selecting cart button in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

The cart button has the following html information.
How should I select it?
Using as name or id or link_text did not work.
Any idea please..

```
<div>

    <input class="button ui-state-default ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="submit" value="View Items in Cart" role="button" aria-disabled="false"></input>

</div>

from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(any_url)
browser.find_element_by_name('View Items in Cart').click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it has no `id` attribute or `name` attribute or `link-text` attribute.

In fact, it's not even a link (`a`) tag, it's an `input` tag.

As to your question, try using this instead:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="View Items in Cart"]').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do below

1. Get all the Elements by tag name "input".
2. Loop through all the input elements and check the attribute "value" and "role". If they match your specific value in the component i.e. "View Items in Cart" and "button". Then you can do your operation on that element.

Answer (score 1):

I think a little more accurate than barak's answer is to use css (faster look-ups) and use submit() instead of click()

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector( "input[value='View Items in Cart']" ).submit()
```